# Display Response Body on the report JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I try to show a script result on the report

Hello all,
I have written a test where I am trying to determine the total duration of a thread.
I calculate the time with JSR223 script:
[[image: MyScript]]
This is my result:
[[image: Response]]
The results are calculated correctly, but on the HTML report I have only the time from the request.
[[image: LoadTime]]
[[image: Report]]
Does anyone know how I pass the calculated time from the ResponseBody?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set your JSR223 Sampler execution time to the value of your JSR223 Sampler result text you need to use [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the following code:

```
prev.elapsedTime = prev.getResponseDataAsString() as long
```

where `prev` stands for the **prev**ious [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html), see JavaDoc for all functions available with descriptions and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) article for more information on this and other  [JMeter API shorthands](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) available for the [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223).

also remove this `/1000` bit from your JSR223 Sampler code as JMeter elapsed time is in **milliseconds**, if you want it to be in seconds - round it up so it won't have any decimal points.